# scala & lambda & closures

Tags: scala, lambda

Could someone explain what is the difference (and why) between 
Syntax 1 & Syntax 2.

```
object Test extends App {
   def fun(provider: (String) => String) = {
     println(provider("xxx"))
   }

   //Syntax 1
   fun(MyObj.provider.giveString)
   //Syntax 2
   fun(x => MyObj.provider.giveString(x))
}

object MyObj {
   var provider = new StringProvider
}

class StringProvider {
   def giveString(param: String) = param + "_giveString"
}
```

Syntax 1 will create anonymous function that will capture reference to StringProvider, while syntax 2 will not. Why ? Could someone explain me that (or even better point to some documentation)

This is what scala generates.
For Syntax 1:

```
public final class Test$$anonfun$1 extends AbstractFunction1 implements Serializable {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
    private final StringProvider eta$0$1$1;

    public final String apply(String param) {
        return this.eta$0$1$1.giveString(param);
    }

    public Test Test$$anonfun$1(StringProvider eta$0$1$1) {
        this.eta$0$1$1 = eta$0$1$1;
    }
}
```

In case of Syntax 2:

```
public final class Test$$anonfun$2 extends AbstractFunction1 implements Serializable {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    public final String apply(String x) {
        return .MODULE$.provider().giveString(x);
    }
}
```

Regards,
Pawel

Comment: "Syntax 1 will create anonymous function that will capture reference to StringProvider, while syntax 2 will not." - where did you get that from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the eta expansion in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala)

Comment: @YoungSpice edited my question and posted code that scala generates for both calls

Comment: @virtuss That is super similar to another question posted just a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40999190/scala-compilation-anonymized-function You're not the same person, are you? :-)

Comment: @YoungSpice it's not me...but I agree...looks the same. Thanks for pointing